# Problems mounting hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I've connected my hard drive by usb but the contents do not appear in `/media`.

When I mount it manually using `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/user` it succeeds.

When I list the contents of the `fstab` this is what I get:

```
#cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=number /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=number  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I am not sure if the device should appear there, also running lsblk, I see it (sdb1):

```
$ lsblk -f
sdc
└─sdc1 ntfs     username id
```

Why it is not mounting automatically?

**EDIT**: included a better description of the problem.

Comment: When you say you have mounted it but the contents don't appear, what do you mean exactly? How have you mounted it? There is no mention of `/media` in your `fstab` file, so this drive won't be mounted automatically.

Comment: What is the difference between "I've mounted by hard drive" and "When I mount it manually"? How did you mount "by" hard drive? Do you use a command (if so what)? Do you use an app, like Gnome Disk? How is the drive formatted, `ext4`, `NTFS`, or something else?

Comment: If internal drive you want to add an entry to fstab. You have to create mount point, edit fstab and give yourself ownership & permissions if Linux format. If NTFS, it only uses default from parameters in fstab mount. An example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700 If external drive you need extra parameters & if NTFS additional parameters suggested.

Comment: @terdon thanks. I run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/username`, and that is what I mean by manually mounting the external hard drive.

Comment: @user68186 that was very vague but I didn't even noticed it. Updated.

Comment: When you connect the drive, does an icon for it appear on your desktop or in your file manager? If this is a USB drive (which kind of changes everything and wasn't mentioned originally), then it won't be mounted at `/media` but somewhere under `/run/media/`. So, do you see an icon on the desktop?

Comment: @terdon But it was normally (in a fresh installation) mounted in `/media/user`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new entry in the /etc/fstab file.

1. with this command:

```bash
sudo  blkid
```

you get important information which UUID-number your /dev/sdb1 drive have.
Save the number in a text-file.

2. Create the directory for the target path, where you want to mount your new drive. As an example you can chose a folder with the name "mydata" in your home directory. Maybe: "/home/minsky/mydata "

There you can save all your personal data and they are separated from the operating system HDD and the OS-partition.

3. Then you can create the new mountpoint in your fstab file.

Open the /etc/fstab file with:

```bash
sudo mousepad /etc/fstab
```

and create a new line where you can put in a line like this:

```bash
# My 1TByte SSD or HDD
UUID=50eebbff-8f43-4a11-8877-8abb2233246     /home/minsky/mydata    ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,discard,nobh,data=ordered,commit=120          0       2
```

Replace the UUID number in this example with the number from your research.

Now your fstab would looks like this:

```bash
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=number /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=number  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#
# My 1TByte SSD or HDD
UUID=50eebbff-8f43-4a11-8877-8abb2233246     /home/minsky/mydata    ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,discard,nobh,data=ordered,commit=120          0       2
#
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Note:**

You can see the type of the filesystem with:

```bash
df -T
```

If your drive is an SSD (or M.2 - SSD) and formated with f2fs (the flash friendly filesystem), then your mount entry in fstab should looks like this:

```bash
# My 1TByte SSD
UUID=50eebbff-8f43-4a11-8877-8abb2233246     /home/minsky/mydata    f2fs      rw,noatime,nodiratime,nosuid,nodev,discard,background_gc=off,inline_xattr,active_logs=2   0    0
```

If it is an NTFS-filesystem it looks like this:

```bash
UUID=077BBEE22CCA2110       /home/minsky/mydata     ntfs  rw,user,noauto,uid=0,gid=46,umask=007,nls=utf8                  0   0
```

(replace the example-UUID with the UUID of the f2fs or NTFS-partition)

Comment: will accept once i can fully test if it works fine. +1

Comment: You have to mount your new Harddrive and then check which filesystem does it have!  With the command: df -T , you can see the type of filesystem of your new drive.  If it is a ntfs filesystem, then the mount-entry in fstab is different.

Comment: thanks, but it is written in the post

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer for you.